# Two boxes in one row on mobile view

Tags: html, responsive-design, row, responsive

I am using bootstrap for blocks section, currently 5 boxes appearing in one row on desktop, and currently only 1 box appearing in mobile view but I want two boxes in a row on mobile view, please help

```html
<div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6" id="p1"> 
                <a href="#">     
              <div class="text-center icon-box-bg"> 
                  <img src="images/icon/icon-1.png">
                <h4 class="icon-box-title mt-20"><a class="" href="#">Heading</a></h4>
                <p class="icon-box-title-sub">Sub Heading</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-half-offset">
              <div class="text-center icon-box-bg">
                <a href="#" class="">
                   <img src="images/icon/icon-2.png">
                <h4 class="icon-box-title mt-20"><a class="" href="#">Heading</a></h4>
                <p class="icon-box-title-sub">Sub Heading</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-half-offset">
              <div class="text-center icon-box-bg">         
             <a href="#" class="">
                  <img src="images/icon/icon-3.png">              
                <h4 class="icon-box-title mt-20"><a class="" href="#">Heading</a></h4>
                <p class="icon-box-title-sub">Sub Heading</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-half-offset">
              <div class="text-center icon-box-bg"> 
             <a href="#" class="">              
                   <img src="images/icon/icon-4.png">              
                <h4 class="icon-box-title mt-20"><a class="" href="#">Heading</a></h4>
                <p class="icon-box-title-sub">Sub Heading</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-half-offset">
              <div class="text-center icon-box-bg">         
              <a href="#" class="">
                   <img src="images/icon/icon-5.png">
                <h4 class="icon-box-title mt-20"><a class="" href="#">Heading</a></h4>
                <p class="icon-box-title-sub">Sub Heading</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all `col-md-2 col-sm-6` with `col-6 col-md-2`. This will put 2 boxes in 1 row in everything below `md` and 6 boxes (to have 5 you'll have to apply offset) in everything from and above it.

Comment: same result appearing

Comment: Then it's a problem somewhere else, please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/7mr9cszk/5/ Try adjusting the result area, and you'll see the boxes change layout.

Answer (score 0):

As per `bootstrap 4 library` add `col-6` to every div with class `col-md-2 col-sm-6`.

This will limit the boxes in 6 grid, so in mobile screen you can view 2 boxes in a row

Comment: same result appearing